# Set cell size to not go past certain width & height

Tags: html, css

I originally hardcoded my width and height of cells.  But we went against that.  Now I want it to behave as is,shrinking and expanding, but stop once it gets to a certain width.

[image]

```
  <table align="center" class="data_extract vert_scroll_table" >
              <tr>

                  <c:forEach var="heading" items="${results.headings}"> 

                      <th class="data_extract">${heading}</th>

                  </c:forEach>
              </tr>
              <c:forEach var="row" items="${results.data}">
                  <tr>
                      <c:forEach var="cell" items="${row}" varStatus="rowStatus">
                          <td class="data_extract">
                              <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
                                    <c:set var="comma" value="," />
                                        <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
                                            <c:set var="myVar" value="${cellStatus.first ? '' : myVar} ${elem} ${cellStatus.last ? '' : comma}" /> 
                                        </c:forEach>
                                        <span class="mouseover_text" title="${myVar}">${myVar}</span>
                                    </c:when>
                                  <c:otherwise>
                                        ${cell}
                                  </c:otherwise>
                              </c:choose>
                          </td>
                      </c:forEach>
                  </tr>
              </c:forEach>
              </table>
```

css:

```
table.data_extract
{

 border: 2px gray solid;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 }

td.data_extract,
th.data_extract,
table.data_extract td,
 table.data_extract th

{

 text-align: center;
 font-size: 7.5pt;
 white-space: normal;


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `max-width: {whatever width you want}` and `min-width: {whatever width you want}` to your td.data_extract rule.

Comment: hey buddy ...I added this just to test `td.data_extract,
th.data_extract,
table.data_extract td,

 {
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7.5pt;
  white-space: normal;
  max-width: 5px;
  
 }` and the table looks exactly the same

Comment: @Doc Holiday, there is a syntax error in the rule you added (spurious comma before “{”).

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS min-width and min-height properties

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Comment: As mWillis mentions, there are also `max-` variations